# How to select between a minimum and maximum range

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to generate random player weightings based in the league they play in. I have got this working when there was only one leagueWeighting (which was the maimun league weighting per league), but I want to include a MinLeagueWeighting as well so that it starts from that number and not 0.

I just need help on the select statement in the scarlar function in order to be able to random select a player weighting between the min value and the max value:

Below is the league_insert proc to determine the max and min weightings per league:

```
UPDATE League
SET MaxLeagueWeight =
(
    CASE
        WHEN LeagueID = 1 THEN 90
        WHEN LeagueID = 2 THEN 80
        WHEN LeagueID = 3 THEN 70
        WHEN LeagueID = 4 THEN 85
        WHEN LeagueID = 5 THEN 90
    ELSE 0
    END
    ),
    MinLeagueWeight =
    (
    CASE
        WHEN LeagueID = 1 THEN 50
        WHEN LeagueID = 2 THEN 40
        WHEN LeagueID = 3 THEN 30
        WHEN LeagueID = 4 THEN 45
        WHEN LeagueID = 5 THEN 50
    ELSE 0
    END
    )
```

Below is a view to perform a random:

```
CREATE VIEW Random
AS

SELECT RAND() RandValue
```

Below is the scarlar function that needs to select a player weighting for each player between the lowest and highest possible league weighting (this is where I think the fix is needed):

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_PlayerWeighting]
(   
    @MaxPlayerWeighting INT,
    @MinPlayerWeighting INT
)
RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE @playerWeight INT

    SELECT  @playerWeight = ROUND(( ( @MaxPlayerWeighting - 0 - 1 ) * (SELECT RandValue FROM Random) + 0 ), 0)

    RETURN @playerWeight;


END
```

Below is the function being updated and selected:

```
UPDATE Player
SET PlayerWeighting = dbo.fn_PlayerWeighting (l.MaxLeagueWeight, l.MinLeagueWeight)
FROM Player p
INNER JOIN Team t
    ON t.TeamID = p.TeamID
INNER JOIN League l
    ON l.LeagueID = t.LeagueID



    SELECT dbo.fn_PlayerWeighting (l.MaxLeagueWeight, l.MinLeagueWeight) 
FROM Player p
INNER JOIN Team t
    ON t.TeamID = p.TeamID
INNER JOIN League l
    ON l.LeagueID = t.LeagueID
```

Comment: You don't need the view. You just need to handle your RAND in your fn_PlayerWeighting function. Here's some great info on how to keep your RAND value between the ranges you want. http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/04/29/sql-server-random-number-generator-script-sql-query/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this in your function.

```
SELECT  @playerWeight = ROUND(((@MaxPlayerWeighting - @MinPlayerWeighting -1) * RAND() + @MinPlayerWeighting ), 0)
```

Comment: Thank you very much